# Angularjs - Two config functions in the same module

Tags: angularjs

I configured my routes in the module and it's working pretty good, but I'm also trying to add a loading indicator,which will intercept any http request and put a loading image but it's not working. Here's my module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
 function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider
         .when("/", {
             templateUrl: "/pages/home.html"             
         })
         .when("/currency", {
             templateUrl: "/app/series/currencySearch.html",
             controller: "currencyController"
         })
         .when("/others", {
             templateUrl: "/app/series/genericSearch.html",
             controller: "genericController"
         })
         .otherwise({
             redirectTo: "/"
         });
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
 }]);

    myApp.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div style="margin:20% 0 0 50%;"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></div>';
}]);
```

It's possible to use two config functions this way?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why can't you initialize your loader in run block instead config..

Comment: You can certainly have as many `.config` functions as you want. Perhaps you should describe the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. It will just run them one after another.

That way, if you want to, you could write a separate config method for each $provider object.

The question is, why does it have to have two configs? It should work fine as one config method.

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", "cfpLoadingBarProvider",
 function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
     $routeProvider
         .when("/", {
             templateUrl: "/pages/home.html"             
         })
         .when("/currency", {
             templateUrl: "/app/series/currencySearch.html",
             controller: "currencyController"
         })
         .when("/others", {
             templateUrl: "/app/series/genericSearch.html",
             controller: "genericController"
         })
         .otherwise({
             redirectTo: "/"
         });
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
     cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div style="margin:20% 0 0 50%;"><span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></div>';
 }]);
```